# Avoid data replication in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a main table like this:

```
properties_table
- property_id
- property_name //I.E. Apartment 4 rooms
- property_type //can be house, apartment, land, space
- whater // available only for apartments/houses/spaces
- heat // available only for apartments/houses
- pvc // available only for apartments
- land_type // available only for lands
- apartment_type // available only for apartments
- house_type // available only for houses
- space_type // available only for spaces
- floors // available only for apartments/houses
- faience // available only for apartments/houses
- tiles // available only for apartments/houses
```

The problem is if I add a land I would have a lot of NULL or 0 in the fields that does not correspond to a land and I don't like to do this, so how can I avoid replication of NULL in my case? To split the table for each property_type?

I select the data from database using the id.

I.E. http://example.com/id=5

Comment: You need multiple tables.  Instead of holding that data in the properties_table... create a table for each and link them with property_id

Comment: And the select? This is the problem, if I have a url like:  http://example.com/id=5, the select would be: `select * from properties_table a LEFT JOIN ?????? b ON a.property_id = b.property_id where a.property_id = 5;`

Comment: You should clarify in your question that you are using parameters passed from a URL.

Comment: @KyleWilliamson I edited my question, thank you.

Comment: @BK435 something like this? http://pastebin.com/LqLNJFGb

Comment: You need to decompose your table into several tables. My guess is that you have many replications in your data.

Comment: Something like in my previous comment? http://pastebin.com/LqLNJFGb

Comment: If you have any schelet of tables post as answer and if is ok I will accept as answer :)